# How to extract the zipped xls file from the email attachment?

Tags: excel, perl, email, zip, email-attachments

I have a module which is supposed to extract the email attachment and place it at a specific location. The code creates the POP3 Client to fetch the mail and has been using **EMAIL::MIME::Attachment::Stripper** module to extract the attachment as below.

```
     my $mail=$pop->HeadAndBody($i);
     my $parsed = Email::MIME->new($mail);
     my $stripper = Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper->new($parsed);
     my @attachments = $stripper->attachments;

     foreach my $a(@attachments)
     {
        next if $a->{content_type} !~ /octet-stream/i;
        my $f = new IO::File "C:/MAIL_PARSING_DATA/" . "<filename>.<file-extension>", "w" or die "Can not create file!";
        print $f $a->{payload};
        goto EXITPOINT;
     }
```

The code is working fine for the standard files identified by the Perl module, like spreadsheet etc. But not for the specific mail which has a **zipped Excel file** as an attachment. While extracting the file the identified **content_type** by the Perl script for this file is **application/octet-stream**. While extracting the file using the above-mentioned code the file seems to be broken because:

1. The file is not getting opened through WinZip, WinRAR or 7-Zip.
2. File size for the file extracted through this script is slightly different than the same file extracted using Outlook.

Kindly provide some input on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
next if $a->{content_type} !~ /octet-stream/i;
```

zip have content type as application/zip

Answer (score 0):

@NeoNox, Thanks for the response. But the perl system identifies the file as octet-stream only, not with application/zip.

Anyways, I could find the solution.

I could resolve the problem by writing the file in the binary mode(mentioning explicitely as below:

```
    binmode $fh;
```

Here the file is being writting in the binary mode So I don't get the output as the broken file.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding the same issue.

XLSX files are not seen as attachments.
I am using IMAP.

It will download the email body, any jpgs or pngs etc but does not find the attached xlsx even when in an email that has attachments that are downloaded.